# How to speed up a while-loop in R (perhaps using dopar)?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, parallel-processing, doparallel

I'm trying to process a huge text file containing dozens millions lines of text. The text file contains the results of a convnet analysis of several millions of images and looks like this:

```
 CUDNN_HALF=1 
net.optimized_memory = 0 
mini_batch = 1, batch = 8, time_steps = 1, train = 0 
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 

 seen 64, trained: 447 K-images (6 Kilo-batches_64) 
Enter Image Path: data/obj1/H001683-19-1-5-OCT2 [x=13390,y=52118,w=256,h=256].png: Predicted in 19.894000 milli-seconds.
tumor: 99%  (left_x:    2   top_y:  160   width:   67   height:   34)
bcell: 98%  (left_x:    6   top_y:   54   width:   32   height:   22)
bcell: 80%  (left_x:   51   top_y:    0   width:   30   height:   16)
bcell: 98%  (left_x:   52   top_y:  198   width:   28   height:   26)
bcell: 98%  (left_x:  150   top_y:  216   width:   35   height:   23)
bcell: 56%  (left_x:  150   top_y:   78   width:   45   height:   30)
bcell: 91%  (left_x:  187   top_y:  132   width:   31   height:   26)
bcell: 96%  (left_x:  219   top_y:  185   width:   20   height:   26)
bcell: 37%  (left_x:  222   top_y:   -0   width:   24   height:    4)
bcell: 98%  (left_x:  241   top_y:  208   width:   15   height:   21)
bcell: 64%  (left_x:  248   top_y:   35   width:    8   height:   35)
 [... a lot of similar lines...] 
Enter Image Path: data/obj1/H001683-19-1-5-OCT2 [x=13390,y=52530,w=256,h=256].png: Predicted in 19.195000 milli-seconds.
bcell: 97%  (left_x:   45   top_y:  180   width:   29   height:   24)
bcell: 58%  (left_x:   59   top_y:    1   width:   35   height:   22)
tumor: 98%  (left_x:  105   top_y:  143   width:   99   height:   44)
tumor: 97%  (left_x:  113   top_y:   50   width:   57   height:   40)
bcell: 96%  (left_x:  191   top_y:  194   width:   29   height:   27)
bcell: 99%  (left_x:  201   top_y:  129   width:   34   height:   22)
Enter Image Path:
```

Each image is mentioned by the image file name after "Enter Image Path" followed by a list of objects which were identified. I do not know a priori, how many objects (here tumor an bcell) are in each image. Sometimes where are no objects at all, sometimes where are hundreds.
I first tried to read the whole file using

```
test11<-readLines("result.txt")
picsna<-grep(test11,pattern="Enter Image") # line numbers with the image file name
lle<-length(picsna) # length for the subsequent script
```

and then to go ahead with my script but it proved to take hours to read the file so I came with the Idea to read the file line by line and execute my code "on the fly" using a `while`-loop:

```
require(LaF)
n=1 
lle<-0 # number of images (to be used in a subsequent code) 
picsna<-c() # vector with the line numbers of each image entry

# read the result-file initially (first bunch of lines do not contain image entries
test11<-get_lines(file="result.txt", line_numbers=n) 
# as long as the line exists read the next line and do following:
while(is.na(test11)==FALSE){ 
  test11<-get_lines(file="result.txt", line_numbers=n+1)
# I wanted to know how far my reading progressed but had a feeling, print slowed down the loop
  #print(n)   
# I found here this solution for printing progress periodically 
  if(n %% 10000==0) { 
     cat(paste0("iteration: ", n, "\n"))
  }
# look for image entry and save the line number (not the iteration number)
  if(grepl(test11,pattern="Enter Image")==TRUE){ 
    picsna<-c(picsna,n+1)
    lle<-lle+1} # increase the number of images
  n<-n+1 
}
# the last line of the file is always incomplete but has to be added to the vector to calculate the number of objects (in a following script not shown here) if the previous image had any.
if(is.na(test11)==TRUE){ 
  picsna<-c(picsna,n)
  print("The End")
  lle<-lle+1
}
```

I measured the elapsed time for the first and the second script on a small result file containing about 200 lines. The second script was even a little bit slower (0.04 vs 0.01), which confused me.
I thought about rewriting it in a `foreach`-`%dopar%`-loop but could not realize how to implement it with the `readLines`-function or with  my `while`-loop. My problem is, that I do not know apriori how many lines the file contains. I would really appreciate if somebody could help me to parallelize my script!

Comment: How long does a simple command line script run? For example, `grep -hn -R "Enter Image" result.txt | cut -f1 -d:` gives you the line numbers that match. If that runs fast enough, you could consider doing this search of line numbers outside of R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Bas! I tested your suggestion on a Linux machine: for a file with ~239 million lines  it took less than 1 min. By adding `>lines.txt` I could save the results. Interestingly, my first `readLines` R script needed "only" 29 min, which was surprisingly fast compared with my first experience (so I might have had some problem with my Windows computer at work which was not related to R).